# Import Text File with Blank Characters

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate a task in VBA where I click a button to select a text file (which is a generated output file from another program) and the text file then imports itself into the workbook to be parsed.  The text file is space delimited with inconsistent breaks (some lines contain 8 characters per value, others contain 10, etc).  My problem is when Excel imports lines that contain blank spaces (" ") that Excel loses the leading/trailing spaces if there's only one non-blank value in that given row.  My code is given below:

```
Sub Import_File()
Sheet3.Cells.Clear
Sheet3.Activate
x = Application.GetOpenFilename
If x = False Then
Exit Sub
End If
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & x, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

A workaround I read is that I could manually open the text file in Notepad, and find/replace all spaces with a character not in use, such as %, and then import so I can parse the data. I'd prefer to automate this task and avoid using Notepad.  I found code below that modifies the text file itself and performs the character swap (the given code searches the text file for string given in cell A1 and replaces it with string in cell B1).  The "Replace_Text" code works except I just want to temporarily modify the text file so that I can perform a proper import and wish to preserve the original text file afterward.  Is there a clean way to piece together this code to perform a proper import and avoid permanently altering the original text file? EDIT: Added a snapshot of my text file that isn't importing properly if this helps. The leading spaces on the 10th entry of the 4th row are being ignored when Excel imports the file.

```
Sub Replace_Text()
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strText As String
Dim cell As Range
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
i = FreeFile
strText = Space(FileLen(strFile))
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    Open strFile For Binary Access Read Write As #i
        Get #i, , strText
        For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            .Pattern = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "?", "\?"), "*", "\*"), "+", "\+"), ".", "\.")
            strText = .Replace(strText, cell.Offset(, 1).Value)
        Next cell
        Put #i, 1, strText
    Close #i
End With     
End Sub
```

[Link to Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvT15.png)

Comment: I don't see where you've ever set the `space` as a delimiter.  I notice you have `tab` and `comma` set as delimiters, but you write that your file is `space` delimited.  Which is it?  If it is `space`, then set only that delimiter (and unset the others), and set the consecutive delimiter property to false and see what happens.  If it is not really a space, then which is it?  `tab` or `comma`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion altering the delimiters but it's not producing what I need. My file is space delimited but fixed width per entry (but can vary depending on the line). Some lines the entry is 16 characters long, other lines may be 8, etc.  If I can get the data properly imported I planned on parsing the data using the Mid() expression. Importing as space delimited still appears to ignore/lose leading spaces. In one line of my text file there is an entry in the 10th "column" but the rest of the columns are blank. Excel ignores the leading spaces and stores it an entry in the 1st column.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.  Either you are not sharing something important, or you have not properly implemented the import routine, or I am not understanding the issue. Without sufficient data to reproduce your problem, I don't know what to say.  If I have a space delimited "csv" file, and set it up as I described, it imports where each space will delimit a separate column.  So if there are eight spaces, there will be eight columns.  If there are `3 spaces/string/3 spaces/String` the strings will be in columns 4 and 8

Comment: I also tried setting the consecutive delimiter property to false which distorts the data quite a bit more. If I have a row with one entry with a value that's 6 characters long (w/2 leading spaces) and the next entry is 5 characters long (w/3 leading spaces) it produces an extra empty column between these values due to the extra space.  The number of spaces between each entry varies depending on how many characters/digits the value has.

Comment: It sounds like you do not have a space delimited file, but rather a fixed width file. If that's the case, you will need to know (or be able to determine), the width of each column.

Comment: I added a link with a snapshot of my text file in my original post. You're right, it's a fixed-width file.  My issue is that the width varies depending on the row. I think if I can get code working to temporarily replace "space" characters in the text file and substitute another character (such as %) that it will import data correctly and I should be able to parse the data off of that. The Replace_Text code I have above works for me other than I'd prefer the changes to the text file be temporary (or have my code produce a duplicate modified text file) so I can retain my original text file.

Comment: The screen shot you posted looks like the file is fixed width with 8 characters per column.

Comment: Why not just import it as a fixed width file?

Comment: The fixed width varies throughout the file quite a bit so I think I'll have better luck writing everything to column A on import and then follow with a macro to parse the data. I know it's less efficient than parsing directly from the text file but probably easier for me to code.

Comment: Again, it seems as if they sample you posted would not allow anyone to reproduce your problem. How can you tell, from line to line, what the fixed width happens to be for that particular line?

Comment: I don't understand how replacing space with something else enables you to determine where to parse a fixed width line.  If you can do that with a token, you should be able to do the same thing with a space.  And there are faster ways to do it.